# Integrating Facebook with Website - understanding token access

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm struggling to get my head around Facebook API to integrate bits into an admin website. I've been able to easily integrate twitter and google analytics but not facebook.

What I want to be able to do is display the current number of likes for the FB page and get latest posts - ideally then be able to submit posts to the same FB page as summary of news items posted on the admin site.

There are a few users each logging in to my admin site but only one login for the FB page.

Can I hard code the credentials into my website (stored securely). I've looked at loads of docs on the subject which all require a user to log in (using their own FB details) but I don't think this is what I need.

What I don't want is to integrate FB login into my account which there seems to be loads of info on.

Is what I'm after possible? If so, how do I go about this and are there any good tutorials to walk me through the process?

I'm using Laravel and  have installed FB SDK and been able to get a token from facebook but only by copy and paste from the api explorer

Thanks

Comment: Get a Page access token, extend it. It will be valid as long as the page admin that granted it does not change their password.

Comment: Thank you - I've now done that and working - thanks